# Multipart request getting terminated from client side while the server is processing the request in spring rest template

Tags: java, spring-boot, multipartform-data, quarkus, resttemplate

I have 2 services `service A`, `service B`.

- `service A` => written in `spring-boot, java`
- `service B` => written in `quarkus, java`.

I'm doing a multipart request to `service A`. The request contains a

```json
    {
        field1: String,
        field2: MultipartFile //This is an image file
    }
```

`Service A` is suppoed to forward the 2nd field `field2` to `service B` via a POST request to the url `http://localhost:8080/upload`.
`Service B` is working fine when a direct POST request is sent to the url `http://localhost:8080/upload`. So, I assume `service B` does not have any problem.

In `Service A` I have,

controller function:

```java
@PostMapping
    public String createPost(@ModelAttribute PostDTO post) {
        return postService.create(post);
    }
```

service function:

```java
public String create(PostDTO postDto) {
        String fileName = uploadFiles(postDto.files());
        //other logics
        return "<upload status>";
    }
private String uploadFiles(MultipartFile files) {
        try {
            FileUploadRequestDTO request = new FileUploadRequestDTO(files);
            HttpHeaders headers = new HttpHeaders();
            // MediaType.MULTIPART_FORM_DATA
            headers.setContentType(request.getContentType());
            // calculated as per the received content
            headers.setContentLength(request.getContentLength());
            HttpEntity<MultiValueMap<String, Object>> requestEntity = new HttpEntity<>(request.getBody(), headers);
            ResponseEntity<FileUploadResponse> uploadResponse = rt.postForEntity("http://localhost:8080/upload", requestEntity, FileUploadResponse.class);
            if (uploadResponse.getStatusCode().is2xxSuccessful()) {
                return Objects.requireNonNull(uploadResponse.getBody()).fileName();
            } else {
                throw new FileUploadFailed("Storage Engine returned error response");
            }
        } catch (IOException e) {
            throw new FileUploadFailed("could not retrieve file size of the attached file");
        }
    }
```

I think there is some problem in the `uploadFiles()` function foe which the connection is getting terminated imporperly.

From `service B` I'm recieving

```bash
IOError processing HTTP request to /upload failed, the client likely terminated the connection. Error id: <some string>: java.io.IOException: Connection terminated parsing multipart request
```

Please suggest some changes that I can do

Answer (score 0):

There is some problem with the header in a way the content length is calculated I suppose:

```java
 headers.setContentLength(request.getContentLength());
```

As soon as I remove this header the request no longer terminates